# It's not possible to unfollow a deleted discussion

Tags: bug, status-review, discussions-space, unfollow

I followed a few [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions), mainly to see if and how they get handled. Most of them ended up being deleted (as expected), but now I can't unfollow them anymore, because I "Can't vote on discussion post":

[image]

Comment: I can also confirm I can't unfollow a discussion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFMN2.gif